# How to configure a PhoneGap Android to create android App in Windows?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

I have to configure Phonegap to create android App in windows but I am facing some issues . I have been taking help from a tutorial . But when I try to create the project in commandline , it throws an error

```
Missing one of the following:
JDK: http://java.oracle.com
Android SDK: http://developer.android.com
Apache ant: http://ant.apache.org
```

Plz help .

Comment: Make sure you have all of them installed and have entries in the path environment variable. So that they could be run from any location in command prompt

Comment: If you already have these all then try to reinstall each and keep one thing in mind that do not delete or move any file from them.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me and I solved this way:

First verify you actually have these requirements installed, run these commands:

```
java -version
ant -version
android
```

If none of them throws a `not recognized command` error, then you're good to go and:

1. Make a copy of create.bat (just to keep the original)
2. Edit `create.bat` and remove the checking part and let it like this:

`@ECHO OFF`

`cscript "%~dp0\create.js" %*`

It works fine for me.

Edit: If one of those commands are not recognized then you have to check your PATH variable.